# cellForRowAtIndexPath (need to use one string and one integer values in the indexpath)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, row, nsindexpath, nsuinteger

Dear all
I am trying to display two different arrays in one tableView.
I declared "years" array as strings and "amount" array as integers.
      years                 amount
e.g: 2012, 2013 ....      155888,    151768
When I build7run the application the outcome is like below:
(it looks like it decrements numbers by 16)

```
 Remaining Amount On
```

2012:      80912864
 2013:      79047056
 2014:      79046640
 2015:      79046640
 2016:      79051632
...
 2020:      80928544

The "year" array works as it is string but the integer array which is "amount" does not.
I am pretty sure that I am doing wrong in the **cell.text=**  line with the integer number formatting.
I would be very happy if you could help to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"remainingAmountOn";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
**cell.text =** [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@   %d", [years objectAtIndex:row],
```

[NSNumber numberWithInt:[amount objectAtIndex:row]]];

```
return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSNUmber numberWithInt:someInt]
```

returns an NSNumber object and should be formatted with %@.

Alternately, skip the NSNumber bit and just use the int with %d.

At the moment, you're mixing the two.